# How to refer to the question asked in the title of essay

Tags: single-word-requests

In an essay, the title is in the form of a question (e.g. Are those needed anymore?). At the end of the essay and based on the discussed facts, I want to answer the very early question. How should I refer to the question? Options like aforementioned or main question are not desirable. I'm looking for something more specific and interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple.

### Titular Question

> *titular*, adj [[MW](http://i.word.com/idictionary/titular)]: of, relating to, or constituting a title